# How can I make 'submit' in html delete a variable in python? (I am using Flask)

Tags: python, html, django, flask, jinja2

I am trying to make {{password}} change to a different password each time  'submit' is pressed. I am using Flask with html to do this. The function that creates the password is written in python.

I have tried making password an empty string in the Flask file expecting it to be empty each time 'Submit' is pressed. However, it did not change the password. I am trying to change {{password}} to a new {{password}} each time submit is pressed.

```
from flask import Blueprint,render_template, request, g
from gen import main


#This is where the different website pages will be implemented with python
views = Blueprint(__name__,'views')

@views.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('home.html')

@views.route('/index.html')
def generator():
    return render_template('index.html', password = '')

@views.route("/result", methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def result():
    password = ''
    return render_template("result.html",password = password + main())
```

```
def main():
    pword =''
    while True:
        x = randint(randint(20,30),randint(30,40))
        randoml = []
        while len(password) < x:
            lettersL = letters(alphabet)
            numbersL = numbers(alphabet)
            symbolsL = symbols(alphabet)
            randoml.append((random.choice(lettersL)))
            randoml.append((random.choice(numbersL)))
            randoml.append((random.choice(symbolsL)))
            if len(randoml) > 10000: password.append(random.choice(randoml)) 
        pword = ''.join(password)
        return pword
```

```
<html>
    <head>Generated Password</head>

    <body>

        <form class = "password" action = "/result" method = "POST">
            <center>
                {% if password%}
                <h3 style="color: rgb(216, 44, 216)">Your password is {{password}}</h3>
                {% endif%}
            </center>
        </form>
        <form class = "grid" action = "/result">
            <center>
            <input type="Submit" class ="file_submit" value="Generate New Password">
                {% if password%}
                <h3 style="color: rgb(216, 44, 216)"></h3>
                {% endif%}
            </center>
        </form>


    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is `password` a global?  You don't reset it in `main`, so if it had a value from a previous run, your loop will exit immediately.  To be honest, your attempt at randomization here is a bit silly. There is NO point in generating 10,000 things and picking one.  Just generate it once.  And just use `x = randint(20,40)`.  What you're doing is pointless.  You can't make things "more random".  They're either random or they aren't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need an infinite while True loop on your main function.

Here is how I would do it:

```
from flask import Blueprint, render_template
from gen import generate_password

views = Blueprint(__name__, 'views')

@views.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('home.html')

@views.route('/index.html')
def generator():
    return render_template('index.html', password='')

@views.route("/result", methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def result():
    password = generate_password()
    return render_template("result.html", password=password)

def generate_password():
    x = randint(randint(20, 30), randint(30, 40))
    randoml = []
    while len(randoml) < x:
        lettersL = letters(alphabet)
        numbersL = numbers(alphabet)
        symbolsL = symbols(alphabet)
        randoml.append((random.choice(lettersL)))
        randoml.append((random.choice(numbersL)))
        randoml.append((random.choice(symbolsL)))
    password = ''.join(random.sample(randoml, x))
    return password
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a much simpler and better performing mechanism for generating a password.

```
import random

letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
numbers = "0123456789"
symbols = '$_&%'

def main():
    alphabet = list(letters + numbers + symbols)
    random.shuffle(alphabet)
    x = random.randint(20,40)
    return ''.join(alphabet[:x])

print(main())
print(main())
print(main())
```

Output:

```
v3br$_dtcf4y5qzmg&ojw61n0%lk
p2$307t1&h9dlezqj6oambyis%fv54n_rkxcw8
wpdx8k_0ovr&saj76$z19hg5i2%ytn3e4lu
```

Comment: thank you. I knew there was a simpler way of doing it but I got caught up in trying to make the "best" generator lol. But thank you, this is my first project without an assignment to follow so I do appreciate seeing a different pov.